# Updates broke GPaste clipboard manager

Tags: updates, clipboard-manager

The latest Ubuntu 20.04.4LTS updates (done late yesterday) seem to have broken my clipboard manager, GPaste v3.36.3.  GPaste now appears to start but does not respond and displays nothing when queried.

(Update - After rebooting, GPaste now displays the clipboard history but is unresponsive, cannot add or delete from the history, or quit the program.)

I have tried un-installing and re-installing GPaste, but with the same result.

Any suggestions for how to bring GPaste back to life again?  Thanks!

Comment: Is this the Gnome extension or the apt package that you're using? There seems to be multiple projects with this name, and I'm not sure which one you may be using 

Comment: Not sure that I know.  I installed it using the "Ubuntu Software" GUI (from ubuntu-focal-universe), not by using the command line.  Does that tell you which GPaste it is??

Comment: Final update -- I un-installed GPaste 3.36.3.  It evidently does not run properly under Ubuntu 20.04.4LTS after the 23 March 2022 updates.  It had worked fine before that.

Comment: I have the same issue since 2 days, still can not figure out what triggered this behavior. Gpaste gnome-extension does not pop up properly and hangs. although gpaste taskbar-icon works fine.